# How to hyphenate words with a single quotation mark (apostrophe)?

Tags: hyphenation, mark

Using this [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165647/201011) allows to have LaTeX hyphenates words starting or finishing with a bracket. I'd like to use it also to hyphenate words containing a single quotation mark (called "apostrophe" in French). As my MWE shows, it does not work but I do not really know why… Thank you for your help!

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\lccode`\(`\(
\lccode`\)`\)
\lccode`\'`\'

\begin{document}

Eblouissement eblouissement eblouissement eblouissement eblouissement eblouissement eblouissement

(Eblouissement) (eblouissement) (eblouissement) (eblouissement) (eblouissement) (eblouissement) (eblouissement)

D'eblouissement d'eblouissement d'eblouissement d'eblouissement d'eblouissement d'eblouissement d'eblouissement


\end{document}
```

[image: Text with incorrect hyphenation]

Comment: I guess you're typesetting with XeLaTeX. Such information would be very important. On the other hand, if your document is in French, you should use `babel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's analyze a few versions. In all cases the `showframe` package is employed for the output (but not shown in the code)

## First version (pdflatex)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}

Eblouissement eblouissement eblouissement eblouissement
eblouissement eblouissement eblouissement

(Eblouissement) (eblouissement) (eblouissement) (eblouissement)
(eblouissement) (eblouissement) (eblouissement)

D'eblouissement d'eblouissement d'eblouissement d'eblouissement
d'eblouissement d'eblouissement d'eblouissement

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Comment

No hyphenation, as expected.

## Second version (pdflatex)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\lccode`\(=`\(
\lccode`\)=`\)
\lccode`\'=`\'

\begin{document}

Eblouissement eblouissement eblouissement eblouissement
eblouissement eblouissement eblouissement

(Eblouissement) (eblouissement) (eblouissement) (eblouissement)
(eblouissement) (eblouissement) (eblouissement)

D'eblouissement d'eblouissement d'eblouissement d'eblouissement
d'eblouissement d'eblouissement d'eblouissement

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Commant

You see that there is no overfull. The same happens with `lualatex`.

## Third version (pdflatex)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\begin{document}

Eblouissement eblouissement eblouissement eblouissement 
eblouissement eblouissement eblouissement

(Eblouissement) (eblouissement) (eblouissement) (eblouissement) 
(eblouissement) (eblouissement) (eblouissement)

D'eblouissement d'eblouissement d'eblouissement d'eblouissement 
d'eblouissement d'eblouissement d'eblouissement

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Comment

There are overfull boxes, because of the hyphenation minima stated by `babel-french`, but the “words” containing parentheses and apostrophes are hyphenated.

## Fourth version (xelatex)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\lccode`\(=`\(
\lccode`\)=`\)
\lccode`\'=`\'

\begin{document}

Eblouissement eblouissement eblouissement eblouissement 
eblouissement eblouissement eblouissement

(Eblouissement) (eblouissement) (eblouissement) (eblouissement) 
(eblouissement) (eblouissement) (eblouissement)

D'eblouissement d'eblouissement d'eblouissement d'eblouissement 
d'eblouissement d'eblouissement d'eblouissement

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Comment

This reproduces your issue. What's the difference? XeLaTeX can (and does) use a mapping file for fonts, because of a different algorithm it uses for typesetting. In this mapping file, ASCII apostrophes are substituted with “real” apostrophes U+2019.

## Solution (xelatex)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\lccode`\(=`\(
\lccode`\)=`\)
%\lccode`\'=`\' % not needed
\lccode"2019="2019

\begin{document}

Eblouissement eblouissement eblouissement eblouissement 
eblouissement eblouissement eblouissement

(Eblouissement) (eblouissement) (eblouissement) (eblouissement) 
(eblouissement) (eblouissement) (eblouissement)

D'eblouissement d'eblouissement d'eblouissement d'eblouissement 
d'eblouissement d'eblouissement d'eblouissement

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect solution, thanks a lot! And sorry for not having said that I am actually using XeLaTeX… Concerning the `babel` package, I am already loading `polyglossia`, I was thinking they were kind of redundant?